500 Internal Server Error, Actionview:: Template: Error (4:Deadline Exceeded): in Gitlab while merging
The Problem
When I am trying to merge my feature branch into dev, I'm getting 500 internal server error. I've used Merge Request >> New Merge Request option and selected the source and target branches. It loads for quite a few seconds and gives 500 error.
Logs
Started GET "/-/metrics" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-09-06 12:31:39 +0530
Completed 200 OK in 21ms (Views: 6.3ms | ActiveRecord: 6.0nς) Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 41369ms (Activellecord: 5.2ns)
ActionView:: Template: : Error (4:Deadline Exceeded):

42: %li.diffs-tab 
43: link to url_for(safe_parans.nerge(action: diffs')), data: (target: 'dividiffs', action: "diffs, toggle: tabvue') do 
44: Changes 
45: %span.badge.badge-pill merge_request.diff_size 
46: 
47: #diff-notes-app.tab-content 
48: #new.commits.tab-pane.active
lib/gitlah/gitaly_client/diff_stitcher.rb:15:in 'each'
lib/gitlab/gitaly_client/diff_stitcher.rb:15: in 'cach' lib/gitlab/git/diff_collection.rb:109:in `cach_gitaly_patch'
lib/gitlab/git/diff_collection.rb:49:in 'cach'
lib/gitlab/git/diff_collection.rb:85: in each with_index" lib/gitlab/git/diff_collection.rb:85:in 'decorate!
lib/gitlab/diff/file_collection/base.rb:34: in diff files' lib/gitlab/diff/file_collection/base.rb:11:in 'real size'
app/nodels/merge_request.rb:414:in `diff size'
lib/gitlab/metrics/instrumentation.rb:161:in `block in diff size 11b/gitlab/metrics/method_call.rb:36:in 'measure'
lib/gitlab/metrics/Instrumentation.rb:161:in 'diff size'
app/views/projects/merge_requests/creations/_new_submit.html.han1:45:in `block in _app_views_projects nerge requests_creations_new_submittal
ham11599005342054551249_70093222544028
app/views/projects/merge_requests/creations/_new_subait.htal.hanl:43:in_app_vinas_projects_merge_requests_creations_new_submit_htal haal 159
9005342054551249_70093222544620 app/views/projects/merge_requests/creations/now.htal.hanl:6:in_app_views_projects_surge_requests_creations_newital_al_1962060150098515049
79093248547840
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:116: in 'render"
lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:55:in 'with_locale'
lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:61:in 'with_user_locale'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:428:in 'set locale' 11b/gitlah/middleware/multipart.rb:103:in 'call' 'call'
lib/gitlab/request_profiler/middleware.rb:16:in lib/gitlab/middleware/go.rb:19:in 'call'
lib/gitlab/etag_caching/middleware.rb:13: in call' `block in call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/correlation_id.rb:16:in lib/gitlab/correlation_id.rb:15:in 'use_id'
lib/gitlab/middleware/correlation_id.rb:15:in call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/rails_queue_duration.rb:24:in 'call'
lib/gitlab/metrics/rack_niddleware.rb:17 : in 'block in call'
lib/gitlab/metrics/transaction.rb:55: in 'run'
lib/gitlab/metrics/rack_niddleware.rb:17:in 'call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only/controller.rb:40: in "call call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only.rb:18:in lib/gitlab/middleware/basic_health_check.rb:25:in 'call'
lib/gitlab/request_context.rb:20:in 'call
lib/gitlab/metrics/requests_rack_middleware.rb:29:in 'call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/release_env.rh:13:in call' root@gitlab:/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails#_

I was trying to merge my feature branch into dev branch, but may because of the size it's taking more time and giving 500 Internal server error.
**Note : In Other Projects in GitLab I'm not getting the same error while merging the feature into dev. Only in this particular project which is of more size this issue is appearing. **
